# CSS Styling rows with less row-clears

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve to represent a ordinary

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

into rows taking percentages of width

```
<div class="line">
    <div class="col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col25">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

But for every row I need a `clear-both` which is repetitive and I want it specifically in percentage the style of line is 100% width and every column take a certain percentage but I want columns to take the full width of the row.

Comment: use `flex` instead of `float` (I would say use `inline-block` but then you need to fight the gap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this kind of HTML/CSS :

```css
.col5 { width: 5%; }
.col10 { width: 10%; }
.col15 { width: 15%; }
.col20 { width: 20%; }
.col25 { width: 25%; }
.col30 { width: 30%; }
.col35 { width: 35%; }
.col40 { width: 40%; }
.col45 { width: 45%; }
.col50 { width: 50%; }
.col55 { width: 55%; }
.col60 { width: 60%; }
.col65 { width: 65%; }
.col70 { width: 70%; }
.col75 { width: 75%; }
.col80 { width: 80%; }
.col85 { width: 85%; }
.col90 { width: 90%; }
.col95 { width: 95%; }
.col100 { width: 100%; }

.line {
    margin: 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.col:nth-child(2n) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
    <div class="col col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col25">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col25">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <div class="col col60">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col40">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <div class="col col100">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <div class="col col10">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col20">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col col70">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```